# Azure Service Bus - Acknowledgement for message received by topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am using the azure service bus topic mechanism. Moreover I have 
sent the messages to topic and want to check whether the message sent to the topic or not by programatically.

Code:

```
    message.Properties.Add("Name", "Test");
    message.Properties.Add("Country", "India");
    message.Properties.Add("JsonData",json);

    var client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicName);
    await client.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Is there is any way to get responses or status code for this?

Comment: @user2771704 if the answer is not addressing your question, provide a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When the call to `SendAsync()` is finished and no exception is thrown, you're guaranteed that the message has been delivered to the broker.

For exception that can take place (throttling, entity state, etc), your code will need to handle those. If exception is transient, retries are required to ensure operation is executed. See the list of possible exceptions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions).